# Select a row field with a minimum value of another column using sub query and aggregate function

Tags: sql-server, northwind

Attempting to complete exercises from the following link for the northwind example database in MySQL.

http://laerer.rhs.dk/andersb/basicprog/database/exercises/northwindselect.htm

The Question "Using SUBQUERY...find the minimum *unitPrice* from the table *products*. Use this price to find *productID* and *productName* for the product(s) which has the minimal price." has me a little confused.

The following Query

```
    SELECT ProductID, ProductName 
    FROM products 
    ORDER BY UnitPrice
    LIMIT 1;
```

seems to produce the correct answer but doesn't use a SUB QUERY. Is this standard practice to produce fields from a row having a MIN/MAX value from another column? I.e. without using the aggregate functions `MIN()`/`MAX()`.

I would guess that this method would be computationally expensive; having the DBMS sort the table before printing just the top row.  Would a SUB QUERY or any other method be more efficient? Perhaps using the appropriate aggregate function rather than `ORDER BY`. If so, what query should I use?

Comment: People who know about sql server would be more likely to read the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method finds *one* product with the minimum price.  If there are more than one, then you are missing them.

So, the more general solution is to use something a lot like your query as a subquery:

```
select p.*
from products p join
     (SELECT UnitPrice
      FROM products 
      ORDER BY UnitPrice
      LIMIT 1
     ) pmin
     on p.UnitPrice = pmin.UnitPrice;
```

Actually, the subquery would more commonly be written:

```
     (SELECT min(UnitPrice)
      FROM products 
     ) pmin
```

Both produce the same answer.